# how to write a binary file to comport in 4096 chunks and read comport answer after every 4096 bytes

Tags: delphi

I use the Delphi Comport411f component, and I need to read a binary file to a stream, and then I need to send the stream to the Comport in 4096 byte blocks and read from the Comport after every block is written.

My problem is my code is writing the whole file, and only after that then reads the Comport answers.  I need to read the Comport after every 4096 block is written.

```
AssignFile(OpenFile, '2nd_loader.hex');

Reset(OpenFile, 1);
repeat
  BlockRead(OpenFile, buf, sizeof(buf), fc1);
  Sleep(500);
  if fc1 <> 0 then begin
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
until fc1 <> sizeof(buf);

CloseFile(OpenFile);

Comport1.Write(buf, sizeof(buf));

Sleep(100);
Application.ProcessMessages;

form1.ComPort1.ReadStr(r, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not writing the whole file to the Comport (unless the file happens to be less than 4096 bytes).  You are reading the file until a block that is not exactly 4096 bytes in size is read (ie, the last block in the file), then sending only that one block (and sending garbage since fewer than 4096 bytes were actually read).  You are ignoring everything that came before that block.

You need to call `Comport.Write()` and `Comport.ReadStr()` inside of a loop that reads 4096 bytes on each iteration, eg:

```
var
  buf: array[0..4095] of Byte;
  OpenFile: File;
  fc1, BytesRead: Integer;
begin
  AssignFile(OpenFile, '2nd_loader.hex');
  try
    Reset(OpenFile, 1);

    while not Eof(OpenFile) do
    begin
      fc1 := 0;
      repeat
        BlockRead(OpenFile, buf[fc1], sizeof(buf)-fc1, BytesRead);
        Inc(fc1, BytesRead);
      until (fc1 = sizeof(buf)) or Eof(OpenFile);

      if fc1 = 0 then Break;

      Comport1.Write(buf, fc1);
      ComPort1.ReadStr(r, 20);

      if GetQueueStatus(QS_ALLINPUT) <> 0 then
        Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
  finally
    CloseFile(OpenFile);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(4259): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'GetQueueState'

Comment: @allismin [`GetQueueStatus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644940.aspx) is a Win32 API function, so add the `Windows` unit to your `uses` clause. You shouldn't be calling `Application.ProcessMessages()` in a loop to begin with, but if you do, at least call it only when there is something waiting to be processed.

Comment: @allismin the correct name is `GetQueueStatus` not `GetQueueState`. I fixed that in my answer.